# Table with one row vs Table with vertical list

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm using sql server 2008.
We have a table that stores the information about the client that is using our application.
A simplified version of it looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ClientName | Address1   | Address2 | PostalCode | ClientFullName | ClientNameAbbreviated |  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Name       | 111 Street | 222 Ave  | A1A 1A1    | Full Name      | FN                    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This table holds the data so that reports and general app information can grab the data and not
have it hard coded as values or variables. This table only ever has one row in it.

I was thinking about converting this table into the following format to allow easier readability.
This table is only using to populate a class at the beginning of the application and then the class is used to retrieve the information throughout the program. This following format would allow for changes to be inserts,deletes, and updates when a client wants more,less, or different information instead of structural changes. Since this table only ever has one row in it, it would never need structural changes, besides possibly increasing length of fields.

```
-----------------------------------------------
| ID                     | Value              |
-----------------------------------------------
| ClientName             | Company Name       |
| Address1               | 111 Street         |
| Address2               | 222 Ave            |
| PostalCode             | A1A 1A1            |
| ClientFullName         | Full Company Name  |
| ClientNameAbbrevation  | CN                 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I was wondered what the pros and cons were in regards to database design, and if there is any unwritten database design golden rules I am breaking by implementing this design?

-- EDIT -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you for the comments so far.

- Point: Breaking 3NF
- Conclusion: Doesn't really apply to this scenario since the first example will only ever have one row.
- Point: All values will be the same datatype and therefore be unable to enforce checks.
- Conclusion: A good point and make me lean towards the first design, but due to certain business rules, check constraints probably won't be able to be enforced on this table.

Comment: Neither design is normalized.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Could you let me know what normal form this breaks? There is only ever one row in the first example and therefore can't break half of the normal forms, except Third but it is all data off of the ClientName. The second example doesn't break up to 4NF and not really concerned with 5NF or about for this table.

Comment: Just remember: *Data should reference the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key (so help me Codd)* - you have several columns in your design that are **not** dependent on the key, the whole key - but instead depend on other (assuming non-key) columns

Comment: Yes, but to me, since there is only over one row in this table then the 3NF doesn't apply because the 3NF is meant to reduce duplication of data, and there is no duplication of data, either horizontally or vertically. I see where you are coming from though.
Looking at it strictly from a 3NF standpoint though, the second design with be closer to 3NF than the first.

Comment: The biggest drawback with the second design as that all the values have to be of the same type. If you use a table with multiple columns and one row, each column can have its own datatype, can have its own constraints, whereas with a single column all values must be convertible to a single datatype.

Comment: So lets say later on you want to add a constraint on postal codes, now that it's intermingled with all of this other data, you can't. You've coded yourself into a corner.

Comment: Ok, so far, theres the breaking of the 3NF, which I don't consider a horrible thing in this case since there is only ever one row and the second example comes closer. The issue with the same datatye is a good point and may be annoying at times but I don't think it will  affect anything large. The point about check constraints is good as well but unfortunately I don't think I will be able to add checks to this table due to certain business rules. *sigh*

Comment: If this is just a control table why do you want to break it into multiple rows like this? Just let it grow as wide as it needs to. This is basically the same thing as a config file of an ini file but in sql. Don't over analyze this, just push out the columns and be done with it. More than likely the data in here is going to be nearly static anyway.

Comment: @Sean Lange, this is exactly what this is, but the client is a client and I was thinking insert and deletes, would be easier to propagate into a live production server and program than alter tables

Comment: If you are concerned this will grow then maybe a table isn't the best choice...or maybe just make it a single column with xml as the datatype. Then you can just shred the xml and it can contain whatever you want.

Comment: The "singleton" table (where the table permits no more than one row) has the advantage of allowing different datatypes for the different values. If the columns are non-nullable then a singleton table by definition always satisfies at least 5th Normal Form. There is no violation of 3NF.

Comment: @sqlvogel Please put your comment into an answer and I'll marked it as the one that solved my question. Thank you everyone, I'll upvote all that helped (GarethD, Kevin Cook, sqlvogel).

Answer (score 0):

You use name/value pairs when the structure needed varies. For example you store products and 50% have a material mix, 2% have a CPU type, 3% have an rpm, and 20% have an energy class. Rather than building a table of maybe a thousand such attributes, you may use the genric approach then. But you do this at a cost: the dbms doesn't know of your content and cannot help you ensure integrity.

In your case you are not in need to make do without the dbms' help. So don't do it. Keep your table as is and let the dbms know what is a string, a number, a date, what is obligatory and what is optional, what must be a valid country ISO code or a string of exactly 13 characters, so that it can ensure correctness.